# Updating JSONB values while keeping not matching one

Tags: laravel, jsonb, postgresql-13

I have a project of Laravel with two tables

Variants

```
id | name | data (jsonb)
```

Devices

```
id | name | variants_id | data (jsonb)
```

Some of the values in Devices tables used from variant but it also has it's own values too.

So when we create a new device we use variant data and save it with devices along with it's own data.

Now when I want to update variant and only update those fields in all the devices without replacing non-matching values.

Is there a better way than running a foreach loop on all devices.

This is what I'm doing right now.

```
foreach($variant->devices as $device)
    {
        $data = $device->data;
        foreach($variant->data as $key => $value)
        {
            $data[$key] = $value;
        }

        $device->data = $data;
        $device->save();
    }
```

This is the data in Variant

```
{"depth": 66.9, "width": 58.2, "height": 100.8, "pit_id": "1234", "variable": false, "liters_per_cm": 3.88194, "measurement_unit": "cm"}
```

This is the data in Devices

```
{"lat": "16.636192", "lng": "19.238912", "depth": 66.9, "width": 58.2, "height": 100.8, "pit_id": "1234", "total_liters": 391.299552, "liters_per_cm": 3.88194, "measurement_unit": "cm"}
```

I hope this makes sense and help will be highly appreciated

Comment: make sure you modal has https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting JSON casting

Comment: Yes it has casting. and my loop mentioned above is working. I'm asking if this is the only way? Can I bulk update all devices?

Answer (score 0):

i believe you can achieve this by where condition

```php
$variant  // you already have 
Device::where('variants_id',$variant->id)->update([
     'data'=> $variant->data
]);
```

is this you want ?

Comment: Thanks but this will update all the other values right? I only want to update the values which matches

Comment: you means `Devices` data key and `variant` data key have different keys ?

Comment: Yes some of them match, I shared both in my question